# Trying to read information in a file into two lists in Python

Tags: python, list, file-io, split, readline

I think this is a relatively simple question but i'm a beginner and having trouble. I have to read in information from a text file into two lists in python.

This is an example of what the text file looks like, it is called 'ratings.txt' and the three colums are movieId|numberofRatings|averageRatings.

```
1|452|3.9
2|131|3.2
3|90|3
4|209|3.6
...
...
1321|2|2.5
...
...
1685|0|-nan
1686|0|-nan
```

I need to read in the second and third columns of numbers into two separate arrays. the second column of numbers needs to be read into a list numRatings. and the third column needs to be read into a list avgRatings. the text file goes from movies 1 to 1686

so `numRatings` needs to be `[452,131,90,....0,0]`
and `avgRating` needs to be `[3.9,3.2,3,....-nan,-nan]`

I think I have to create the lists, and then create loops to read through the text file and store these numbers in the array.

here is my code so far

```
f = open("ratings.txt") #opens the text file
line = f.readline() #reads in one line of the file
a = line.split("|") #splits the line of the file, for example line 1 looks like [1, 452, 3.9]
```

in the above code if I print `a[0]`, `a[1]` and `a[2]` I get `1`, `452`, and `3.9` respectively.

How do I do this over and over again and store my results into the arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really have a CSV-style file, so use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

results = []
with open('ratings.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        results.append(row)
```

You could augment this as needed; append the second and third columns to separate lists, converting them to `int`s and `float()`s, for example:

```
numRatings = []
avgRating = []
with open('ratings.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        numRatings.append(int(row[1]))
        avgRating.append(float(row[2]))
```

If this *were not* a CSV-style file, you'd still use a loop; you'd loop directly over the file object:

```
with open('ratings.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        a = line.strip().split("|")
```

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: See footnote 6 of the [Numeric Types spec](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex): *`float` also accepts the strings “nan” and “inf” with an optional prefix “+” or “-” for Not a Number (NaN) and positive or negative infinity.*

Comment: You answer my questions before I ask them lol. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: It stands for [Not a Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN): *a numeric data type value representing an undefined or unrepresentable value*.

Comment: I do not think this is a CSV file, all the numbers are seperated by |, can you explain more about how to write the code if not a CSV file? how are the values being put in the array? if i only use the not CSV code i'm still getting errors

Comment: @user2292302: It's a pipe-separated file, which is nothing more than a dialect of CSV.

Comment: @user2292302: [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) originally stood for Comma-Separated Values but has become a generic term for variations of that kind of formatting.

Comment: do I still need my previous three lines of code with your answer? because the code seems to work without my three lines but i am unsure if i should delete them or not

Comment: @user2292302: You do not need the previous three lines; this code replaces those.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
In [56]: with open("abc") as f:
    numRatings=[]
    avgRating=[]
    for line in f:
        f,s,t=map(float,line.split("|"))
        numRatings.append(s)
        avgRating.append(t)
   ....:         

In [57]: numRatings
Out[57]: [452.0, 131.0, 90.0, 209.0]

In [58]: avgRating
Out[58]: [3.9, 3.2, 3.0, 3.6]
```

or :

```
In [68]: with open("abc") as f:
    z=zip(*(map(float,line.split("|")) for line in f))
    numRatings=z[1]
    avgRating=z[2]
   ....:     

In [69]: numRatings
Out[69]: (452.0, 131.0, 90.0, 209.0)

In [70]: avgRating
Out[70]: (3.9, 3.2, 3.0, 3.6)
```